# Last Working Day of the Month

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/local/bin
#!/usr/sbin
#!/usr/bin
# Script to Check last working Day of the Month

echo " Enter Month and Year :"
read mon year
cal $mon $year| egrep  "28|29|30|31"|awk 'BEGIN {
        var1=$NF;var2=NF;
        }
        {
        if (NF > 1 &&  NF < 7)
                val=$NF;
        else if (NF == 1)
                val=$NF-2;
        else if (NF == 7)
                val=$NF-1;
        }
        {
                print "Last Working Date is : " val;
        }'
```

Script Output :

```
511@ubuntu:~/Unix$ ./test.sh
 Enter Month and Year :
4 2015
Last Working Date is : 30
511@ubuntu:~/Unix$ ./test.sh
 Enter Month and Year :
5 2015
Last Working Date is : 29
Last Working Date is : 29
511@ubuntu:~/Unix$ ./test.sh
 Enter Month and Year :
7 2015
Last Working Date is : 31
511@ubuntu:~/Unix$ ./test.sh
 Enter Month and Year :
1 2015
Last Working Date is : 30
```

Why the script prints twice while we gives a input as below :

```
511@ubuntu:~/Unix$ ./test.sh
 Enter Month and Year :
5 2015
Last Working Date is : 29
Last Working Date is : 29
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `egrep` search is going to call `awk` once for every line that it sees a "28", "29", "30", or "31".  Months where the 28th lands before the last calendar week will have `awk` called twice, since two lines match your search criteria

You want to always use the second line of the `egrep` search, so you can use a `tail` command to only see the last line:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/local/bin
#!/usr/sbin
#!/usr/bin
# Script to Check last working Day of the Month

echo " Enter Month and Year :"
read mon year
cal $mon $year| egrep  "28|29|30|31"| tail -n 1 |awk 'BEGIN {
        var1=$NF;var2=NF;
        }
        {
        if (NF > 1 &&  NF < 7)
                val=$NF;
        else if (NF == 1)
                val=$NF-2;
        else if (NF == 7)
                val=$NF-1;
        }
        {
                print "Last Working Date is : " val;
        }'
```

Comment: You are right rexroni.

Comment: Thanks Rexroni.. I assume something wrong with conditions :)

Answer (score 1):

With date it is only a two line bash calculation:

```
#!/bin/bash

month="$1"
year="$2"

read -r dow day < <(date -d "$year/$month/1 +1 month -1 day" "+%u %d")

echo "Last working day of the month = $(( day - ( (dow>5)?(dow-5):0 ) ))"
```

The math is: if dow (the day of the week) is bigger than 5, subtract (dow-5) from the day, else, leave day unchanged.

Use as:

```
$ ./script 2 2015
Last working day of the month = 27
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ksh93`:

```
$ printf "%(%A %B %d)T\n" "October 2018 last working day"
Wednesday October 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script relies on the screen output of `cal`.  To do things in a more proper way you could use the `date` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Calculates the last working day (Mon-Fri) of the month

echo "Enter Month and Year:"
read month year
lastdom=`date -d "$year/$month/1 + 1 month - 1 day" "+%d"`
dow=`date -d "$year/$month/1 + 1 month - 1 day" "+%u"`

if [ $dow -ge 6 ] 
then 
        lastwdom=$(($lastdom - $dow + 5))
else
        lastwdom=$(($lastdom))
fi

echo "Last working day is $lastwdom"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script repeats the print because awk is receiving two lines from egrep. But that has already been covered in other answers.

I want to explain some alternative way to solve the problem, shorter, easier.

The program cal could print the week starting on monday (which simplifies the math) when called as this `cal -NMC month year`. Using that:

```
#!/bin/bash

    lastday(){
        printf 'Last Working Date of %s/%s = ' "$1" "$2";
        cal -NMC "$1" "$2" | awk '
            /[0-9]+/{val=$( NF>5?5:NF )}
            END{ print val }'
    }

mon="$1"
year="$2"
lastday "$mon" "$year"
```

Description:

`/[0-9]+/` Select lines with numbers (avoid empty line).

`NF>5?5:NF` Math: If more fields than 5 result is 5, else NF.

`{val=$( ... )}` Select the value of the field.

`END{ print val }'` Only print the value of the last line (line with numbers).

Call it like this:

```
$ ./test.sh 4 2015
Last Working Date of 4/2015 = 30
$ ./test.sh 5 2015
Last Working Date of 5/2015 = 29
$ ./test.sh 7 2015
Last Working Date of 7/2015 = 31
$ ./test.sh 1 2015
Last Working Date of 1/2015 = 30
$ ./test.sh 9 2015
Last Working Date of 9/2015 = 30
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read -p "Please enter date 'yyyymmdd':" dat
yy=`echo $dat|cut -c 1-4`
mm=`echo $dat|cut -c 5-6`

case $mm in

01|02|03)
mm=12
yy=`expr $yy - 1`
dd=`cal $mm $yy|awk -F " " '{print $6}'|grep -v ^$|tail -1`
echo $yy$mm$dd
;;

04|05|06)
mm=03
dd=`cal $mm $yy|awk -F " " '{print $6}'|grep -v ^$|tail -1`
echo $yy$mm$dd
;;

07|08|09)
mm=06
dd=`cal $mm $yy|awk -F " " '{print $6}'|grep -v ^$|tail -1`
echo $yy$mm$dd
;;

10|11|12)
mm=09
dd=`cal $mm $yy|awk -F " " '{print $6}'|grep -v ^$|tail -1`
echo $yy$mm$dd
;;

*) echo "Invalid month"
exit;;
esac
```